# R-package lavaan (structure equation modeling) - How to access estimates for latent variables?

Tags: r

suppose I fit a model in *lavaan* like this:

```
# model
model <- '
  L1 =~ x1 + x2
'  
# fit & summary
fit <- lavaan(model=model1, model.type="sem", data=PE_test)
summary(fit)
```

How can I access the estimates for the latent variable (L1) for every case?
I was looking for some kind of *fit$coeff* using *str(fit)* but I wasn's successful so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried `parameterEstimates(fit)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `predict` function will return latent variable score estimates. For example,

`LatentScoreEstimates <- predict(fit)`